# gfortran WRITE err option causing segfault

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, gfortran

I cannot understand why a simple fortran program causes a segmentation fault under Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty but works fine in Ubuntu 12.04 Precise. I think to have isolated it by using the ERR option of the WRITE command twice :

```
      PROGRAM WRITESEGF2
      WRITE (*,'(I8)',ERR=40) 3.14
   40 CONTINUE
      WRITE (*,'(I8)',ERR=80) 3.14
   80 CONTINUE
      END
```

I compiled it like this :

```
gfortran -O0 -g -fcheck=all -o writesegfault2 writesegfault2.f
```

This is the output in Trusty :

```
(trusty64)$ ./writesegfault2 
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F1B871EA777
#1  0x7F1B871EAD7E
#2  0x7F1B86E42D3F
#3  0x7F1B86EA41B4
#4  0x7F1B872A1D1E
#5  0x7F1B872AC43C
#6  0x7F1B872AE558
#7  0x40088E in writesegf2 at writesegfault2.f:4
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

GDB says :

```
(trusty64)$ gdb ./writesegfault2

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__memcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:153
153 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.
```

In Precise there is simply no output, as expected :

```
(precise64)$ ./writesegfault2
(precise64)$
```

A single WRITE with ERR label seems to work fine, even in Trusty :

```
      PROGRAM WRITEOK
      WRITE (*,'(I8)',ERR=40) 3.14
   40 CONTINUE
      WRITE (*,'(I8)') 3
      WRITE (*,'(E8.3)') 3.14
      END

(trusty64)$ ./writeok 
       3
.314E+01
```

Here is another variant :

```
      PROGRAM WRITESEGF
      WRITE (*,'(I8)',ERR=40) 3.14
   40 CONTINUE
      WRITE (*,'(I8)') 3.14
      END
```

Another segmentation fault seems to be caused by a WRITE with ERR label, folowed by a simple conversion (should be an error instead) :

```
(trusty64)$ ./writesegfault 

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7FF7F2BCB777
#1  0x7FF7F2BCBD7E
#2  0x7FF7F2823D3F
#3  0x7FF7F28851B4
#4  0x7FF7F2C82D1E
#5  0x7FF7F2C8D43C
#6  0x7FF7F2C8F558
#7  0x40088E in MAIN__ at writesegfault.f:4
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Without using labels, it should be an error:

```
  PROGRAM WRITEERR
  WRITE (*,'(I8)') 3.14
  END
```

When running this, in both Trusty and Precise :

```
(trusty64)$ ./writeerror 
At line 2 of file writeerror.f (unit = 6, file = 'stdout')
Fortran runtime error: Expected INTEGER for item 1 in formatted transfer, got REAL
(I8)
 ^
```

I have reproduced all this with different versions of gfortran : 4.6.3 in Precise and 4.8.4 in Trusty, I have also switched them (backporting 4.8 in Precise and installing 4.6 in Trusty), changing architecture (32 and 64 bit), moving binaries. The issue is the same, so I think it is a libgfortran or glib issue...

Question 1) : Why those segmentation faults, why only in Trusty ? Could this be a regression in glibc ?

Question 2) : Is there a flag in gfortran to actually allow for the REAL to INTEGER conversion in the last case ?

Comment: Which versions of `gfortran` do you have installed on the machines?

Comment: Confirmed with 64-bit Trusty, `GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4`. And I also seem to have succeeded in killing `gdb` with a segfault. That's a first for me.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt I have edited the question to show compiler versions and other tests, I think that gfortran is not the problem here, since even switching binaries causes the segfault only in Trusty...

Comment: Does not occur in GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 5.2.1-23ubuntu1~15.10) 5.2.1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it really was a bug affecting some Ubuntu versions, after opening a ticket in GCC bugzilla they reproduced the problem and traced the fix :

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68594

This problem is affecting gfortran 4.8, partly gfortran 4.9 and should be fixed in gfortran 5.0.

I did not find any way to allow the REAL to INTEGER conversion in WRITE() by using gfortran options.